# Разъясните задание пожалуйста

Tags: классы

Поясните задание пожалуйста.

- Реализовать 2 класса
- Предусмотреть возможность визуального представления

Ну 2 класса понятно. К примеру человек и животное.

Но вот 2 пункт я не могу никак понять. Как можно визуально представить класс или объект класса?

Comment: Может, под «визуальным представлением» имеют в виду UML [диаграмму классов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)?

Comment: спрашивать пояснения задания логичнее всего у того, кто вам его дал.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому, что учебное задание должен решать учащийся, а уточнять подробности задания нужно у преподавателя.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно речь идет о банальном перечислении параметров экземпляра класса? xml, json или в свободной форме по собственному желанию, чисто чтобы были понятны классы и отношения между ними:

```
{class: org.myApp.Human, name: 'Boris', age: 18, pet: {class: org.myApp.Dog, name: 'Shurik'}}
```

или вот так `Human{id: 43, name: 'Boris, age: 18, pet: 45}, Dog{id: 45, name:'Shirik', age: 5}`

Comment: Ну т.е. если я буду выводить данные например в таблицу,  то это и будет визуальное представление?

Comment: да, Vlad from Moscow выше расписал лучше

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что "визуальное представление" - это просто вывод объектов класса в выходной поток, как, например, на консоль.

Вы не указали, о каком языке программирования идет речь, но если, например, речь идет о C++, то имеется в виду, что вы должны перегрузить оператор `operator <<` для класса. Или если речь идет о другом языке программирования, как, например, C#, то вы должны переопределить для класса функцию `ToString`, которая форматирует объект в виде строки для вывода.

Comment: Язык Visual Basic

Comment: @TemaGr На самом деле это не имеет большого значения. То есть вам нужен метод, который выводит состояние объекта на консоль, если имеете дело с консольной программой, либо в графическом режиме. Например, если вы объявили класс автомобиль Car. У автомобиля есть, например, скорость, которая может меняться. Вот при выводе объекта на консоль, вы должны вывести значения этих характеристик. То есть должна быть некая форма вывода состояния объекта на консоль, его некоторых свойств.

Comment: можете сами реализовать метод toString() через геттеры и сеттеры, и обращаться к экземляру класса через этот метод

Answer (score 0):

Например классы геометрических фигур. Вы моежете реализовать классы разных по форме фигур, а потом отрисовывать их на экране и тд. Методы поворота, перекраски и тд